# TOGAF : what is architecture repository

Tags: togaf

Currently I am reading **TOGAF** book. My understanding is **architecture repository** is content. I have following questions:

1. Am I correct about **architecture repository**?
2. Is architecture repository a deliverable document?

Please help to me to understand architecture repository. It is my humble request if anyone have sample of **architecture repository** please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Architecture repository holds content from the execution of ADM iterations and more. The more is external reference architectures, standards etc. 
  Architecture repository by itself is not a deliverable as it is a physical realisation when establishing an architectural capability. 
   Deliverables in the TOGAF world is reviewed and signed artifacts and an artifact can be a diagram, catalog or matrix.

Answer (score 2):

**TOGAF Architecture Repository consists of six major components:**

1. The Architecture Metamodel describes the organizationally tailored application of an architecture framework, including a method for architecture development and a metamodel for architecture content.
2. The Architecture Capability defines the parameters, structures, and processes that support governance of the Architecture Repository.
3. The Architecture Landscape presents an architectural representation of assets in use, or planned, by the enterprise at particular points in time.
4. The Standards Information Base captures the standards with which new architectures must comply, which may include industry standards, selected products and services from suppliers, or shared services already deployed within the organization.
5. The Reference Library provides guidelines, templates, patter ns, and other forms of reference material that can be leveraged in order to accelerate the creation of new architectures for the enterprise.
6. The Governance Log provides a record of governance activity across the enterprise.

[Figure - TOGAF 9.1 Architecture Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kb42o.png)

To answer your question:

What inside TOGAF architecture repository are different kind of contents to be classified into these key components:

- Metamodel - definition of models and their inter-relationship including diagrams, and deliverables

  - Reference Library may exist before your projects which includes manuals, standards, books, articles of papers....

Governance Log - is the records & reviews and etc....